# Turtle mouse goto function returning NoneType

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm writing a little game that requires the (x, y) coordinates of the mouse cursor when clicked. I have two functions, the first gets the coordinates, and the second returns a value based on the coordinates. However, when I run onscreen click(goto), it automatically returns `None` and the rest of the code breaks. Here is what I have so far:

```
    def goto(x,y):
        xx = x
        yy = y
        print(xx,yy) #used to check coords are working
        return xx,yy

   def selector():
        turtle.onscreenclick(goto)

        if xx > 0 & yy > 200:
            #do stuff here
```

The issue is that it is firing when `goto` is called and returning `None`, which causes an error in the `if` statement. Is there a way I can wait for the second input (when the user actually clicks somewhere on the screen)?

Comment: You don't `return` anything in `goto`

Comment: @DavidG, apologies, it's in the code. Regardless, the function triggers and returns an automatic None before user has a chance to click screen. Edited in  return to above to avoid duplicate answers

Answer (score 0):

`onscreenclick` doesn't return anything indeed - it wouldn't make much sense since it's argument is a callback function that will only be executed when the user actually clicks somewhere in the screen (iow it's not a synchronous call).

What you want here is to move your logic to the callback (`goto`) function:

```
def goto(x,y):
    xx = x
    yy = y
    # NB : in python, `&` is the 'binary and' operator, 
    # the logical 'and' operator is named `and`
    if xx > 0 and yy > 200:
        #do stuff here

def selector():
    turtle.onscreenclick(goto)
```